# Combining two readMaybe and getLine in haskell

Tags: haskell

In the haskell wikibook, one is asked to write something like this:

```
adding = do 
  putStrLn "enter first number"
  first <- readMaybe <$> getLine
  putStrLn "enter second number"
  second <- readMaybe <$> getLine
  let x = (+) <$> first <*> second :: Maybe Double
  case x of
    Just d -> putStrLn $ "the sum is " ++ show d
    Nothing -> do 
        putStrLn "not good"
        adding
```

This asks for two numbers and then adds them. However I tried to write it a little bit shorter, doing both getlines on the same line:

```
adding2 = do 
  putStrLn "enter two numbers"
  x <- (+) <$> (readMaybe <$> getLine) <*> (readMaybe <$> getLine)
  case x of
    Just d -> putStrLn $ "the sum is " ++ show d
    Nothing -> do 
        putStrLn "not good"
        adding
```

but this doesn't work. It complains about the type of d, and I suspect it is because I haven't said anywhere that it should be a Maybe Double.

Or maybe it is the line `(+) <$> (readMaybe <$> getLine) <*> (readMaybe <$> getLine)`?

How can I fix this?

---

Apparently the problem is that I have two different monads and can't do what I'm hoping to do. I wrote one variant that I'm particularly happy with:

```
adding5 :: IO ()        
adding5 = do 
   putStrLn "enter two numbers"
   let a = readMaybe <$> getLine
   a >>= \ a1 -> a >>= \ a2 ->
      case (+) <$> a1 <*> a2 of 
        Just d -> putStrLn $ "the sum is " ++ show d
        Nothing -> do putStrLn "not good"
                      adding5
```

---

Here is another one following amalloy's suggestion in the comments:

```
adding6 = do
    putStrLn "enter two numbers"
    [a1, a2] <- replicateM 2 (readMaybe <$> getLine)
    case (+) <$> a1 <*> a2 of 
        Just d -> putStrLn $ "the sum is " ++ show d
        Nothing -> do putStrLn "not good"
                      adding6
```

Comment: `readMaybe <$> getLine` gives `IO (Maybe Int)`, so `(+) <$>` gives `IO Int -> IO (Int -> Int)`. you are missing one piece. I can't think of a way to keep it like that without using transformer.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr It's not possible without using either `>>=` or a transformed monad. `<$>` and `<*>` (from Functor and Applicative) are not enough, because it's not possible for the values inside an Applicative context to impact the context itself. In the specific case of IO, the IO value can't influence future IO actions without using `>>=` or something equally powerful. And since we do need to influence future actions (whether to perform the IO action `adding` again), we need `>>=`.

Comment: Your latest version shows a good understanding of how IO works, I think, in particular by reusing `a`. But is less readable than it could be if you used `<-`. You could write something just as concise but more readable like: `[a1, a2] <- replicateM 2 (readMaybe <$> getLine)`. I like this because it gives actual names to the concepts you have as a human writer: "two times, perform the action `readMaybe <$> getLine`, and store the results into locals named `a1` and `a2`".

Comment: @amalloy Neat, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the original function, you had

```
first :: Maybe Double
second :: Maybe Double
```

So when you combined them with `<$>` and `<*>` you were operating in a Maybe context: exactly what you wanted.

But in your new function, your second argument to `<*>` is

```
readMaybe <$> getLine :: Read t => IO (Maybe t)
```

You're now using `<$>` and `<*>` in the IO context, not the Maybe context, and so the things you are trying to add are of type `Maybe t`, not `t`. You can't add values of type `Maybe t` no matter what `t` is, because `Maybe` is not `Num`. So even if you give the compiler enough information to conclude that `t` should be `Double`, this won't work.

You have to either bind the IO values to local unwrapped names, as you did in your first function, or, equivalently, use `>>=` to operate inside of the `IO (Maybe Double)` you have.

Comment: Thanks! You have made me understand the problem. However I'm not clear on how to follow your last paragraph's suggestions, as I can't work out the syntax for >>= to give me what I want. Any hints?

Comment: @neptun Do you know how to desugar `do` notation into nested binds? If not, you should go find out: it's a good thing to know. Once you know that, simply take your first function, and desugar it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm reading on it. It's just that this example happened in the introduction to monads, so I'm not quite there yet. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I believe that I have understood it better now, edited the question with a version which is slightly shorter than the original.